# Hibernate retrieve query not working

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a hibernate implementation inside my JSF2 code trying to list some records from MySQL DB. There are following code snippets: `Search.java` - implementing the querying logic; `Student.java` - implementing the record saving logic.

The problem I am facing is whenever I run `Search.java`, the result returned is 'null'.

Please  note - my DB has already many entries and even when I tried to query `Student myStudent = session.get(Student.class, 23);` it returned me 'null'.
Here 23 is the id field in the SQL table. Also, the table has auto-generated PK as id. I have another class for inserting the records that works perfectly fine.

`Search.java`:

```
public class Search {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // create session factory
        SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
            .addAnnotatedClass(Student.class).buildSessionFactory();

        // create session
        Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();

        try {

            // start a transaction
            Student tempStudent = new Student("bob", "thebuilder", "good", "blabla@bla.com", "(456)-456 5897");
            session.beginTransaction();

            session.save(tempStudent);

            // commit transaction
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            System.out.println("id of the student is " + tempStudent.getId());

            session = factory.getCurrentSession();
            session.beginTransaction();

            System.out.println("student with id " + tempStudent.getId());
            Student myStudent = session.get(Student.class, tempStudent.getId());

            session.getTransaction().commit();

            System.out.println("Done!");
        } finally {
            factory.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Please advise what mistake I might have made here. I've spent hours googling. Also, please forgive me for my (possibly) rookie mistakes, I am new to Hibernate and to this website.

Let me know if I need to post error stack or my `cfg.xml` as well.

Comment: Are you still experiencing the problem or already solved?

Comment: @ujulu - I am still facing the problem

Comment: Can you post your configuration file? Is the `Student` entity mapped to a table named `Survey`?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in your case id of `tempStudent` is 0. You need to get from session by id of saved student.
Try this:

```
Serializable id= session.save(tempStudent);
...
Student myStudent = session.get(Student.class, id);
```

Also you can enable `show_sql` property in your `hibernate.cfg` file. It will log all generated sql, so you can chek if it is ok.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. id of temp student is being saved. This is reflected when System.out.println("id of the student is " + tempStudent.getId()); returns me the auto-generated id for "Bob thebuilder". 
I tried your implementation too, it's didn't work.

Comment: Did you try to enable show_sql? You can see what sql queries are generated.

Comment: Yes, this is the output :


Apr 20, 2016 7:19:46 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
Apr 20, 2016 7:19:46 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Apr 20, 2016 7:19:46 PM org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl configure
INFO: Envers integration enabled? : true
kjjnull
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        survey
        (email, first_name, hood, last_name, tel) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Comment: INFO: Session Metrics {
id of the student is 58
student with id 58
Hibernate: 
    select
        student0_.id as id1_0_0_,
        student0_.email as email2_0_0_,
        student0_.first_name as first_na3_0_0_,
        student0_.hood as hood4_0_0_,
        student0_.last_name as last_nam5_0_0_,
        student0_.tel as tel6_0_0_ 
    from
        survey student0_ 
    where
        student0_.id=?
INFO: HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/survey?useSSL=false]
get complete null
Done!
}

Comment: What result do you get, if try to apply generated query directly to DB? Try the second one (select query), if you are sure that value in DB is inserted.